# Admob Banner On A Surface View

Tags: android, admob, surfaceview

Do you have any ideas how I could include a Admob banner in a surface view? I tried many hours but it didn't work.

Comment: can you please add the code that you tried already?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :) I don't have the code anymore. Sorry

Comment: Think you should try wrapping your SurfaceView to some container and adding standard AdMob banners

Comment: Ok, do you have a sample code?

Comment: You don't have the code anymore? How come?

Comment: I mean i dont have the code samples i tried anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

Your_activity.xml

```
  < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <SurfaceView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

      <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                             android:layout_align_parrent_bottom="true"
                             ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
    </RelativeLayout >
```

Or create AdMob banner from code. See more at https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals